# Paginating in Laravel. Why show only 15 results?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination

Why I obtain just 15 results? We have more than 20000 entries.

**My Controller:**

```
namespace GBCustomer\Http\Controllers;
use GBCustomer\Customer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function listCustomers()
    {
    $customers = DB::table('customers')->paginate(10);


    return view('customer.index',['customers' => $customers]);
    }
}
```

**My route**

```
Route::get('/customer/list', 'CustomerController@listCustomers');
```

**My view (part)**

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID Customer</th>
                                    <th>Firstname</th>
                                    <th>Lastname</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                </tr>
                             <tbody>
                                  @foreach( $customers as $customer )

                                    <tr role="row">
                                      <td> <a href="customer/show/{{ $customer->id_customer }}">
                                        {{ $customer->id_customer }} </a></td>
                                      <td>{{ $customer->firstname }}</td>
                                      <td>{{ $customer->lastname }}</td>
                                      <td>{{ $customer->email }}</td>
                                    </tr>  
                                @endforeach  
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

If I put DB::table('customers')->paginate(1500); show 1500 results paginated in 15 results.

If I put DB::table('customers')->paginate(2000); show 2000 results paginated in 15 results.

If I put DB::table('customers')->paginate(); show 15 results paginated in 15 results.

If I change this line for:

**$customers = Customer::all();  show all results (about 22000) but in one page!**

?¿?¿

Thanks in advance

Comment: `DB::table('customers')->paginate(10);` should give you 10 results. Don't forget `{{ $customers->links() }}` in your view.

Comment: Also try to user your models for loading data. For example: `Customer::paginate(10);`

Comment: Thanks Ron van de Heijden.  I forget {{ $customers->links() }}